# can you override multiple methods with the same superclass method in java?

Tags: java

if i want to have children with different parameters and different fill methods, what is the best way to be able to do the following, keeping in mind that i would have more than this one child with different methods.. I'd have, say, 8 children, all with different methods and params.

the below code is just something i wrote now as an illustration.. I know there is probably errors.. just wrote it real fast:

```
class SuperClass{
    void fill(){
        //generic 
    }
    get(){//generic }
}

class child{
     variables a, b, c;
     @override
     void fill(a, b, c)
     @override
     int get_a(){
           return a;
     }
     @override
     int get_b(){
          return b;
     }
     //etc...
}
```

main.

```
main(){
 int a = 0, b = 0, c = 1;
 Superclass s = new child.fill(a,b,c);
 int i = s.get_a(); 
}
```

I guessed override probbably wouldn't work because the method is different, but how could I accomplish this?

edit:

i realize the code has provlems (ie. extend), but i wrote it in 45 seconds.. I am looking for a way to inherit in multiple children that hold different variables and need different setters/getters

Comment: `s.get_a()` is syntax error. `get_a()` is absent in `SuperClass s`. Moreover, `new child.fill(a,b,c)` doesn't make sense. :(

Answer (score 1):

No, that does not work.

You cannot change the method signature when overriding methods (except narrowing the return type and exceptions).

You can of course overload the method multiple times (and override those), but the superclass needs to know all combinations.

An alternative could be to have a single bean as the argument, and make that a generic type. Every subclass can then define the appropriate object type. But we need to know more about the concrete case here to suggest a good solution.

Primarily, you have to think about who is calling that code. If they need to come up with completely different parameters to call a method, it seems that there is already strong coupling between caller and callee, so it is unclear what abstraction the common superclass interface can provide here.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot `@override` since the method signature is different (one accepts arguments and the other doesn't.

Second, the syntax is wrong, you can't do:

```
void fill(a, b, c)
```

you probably want either to declare the method `abstract` or do:

```
void fill(a, b, c){}
```

The syntax is also wrong on the following line:

```
new child.fill(a,b,c);
```

split it into two separates line:

```
Superclass s = new child();
s.fill(a,b,c);
```

Further, `get_a()` and `get_b()` don't exist in the parent class.

And last, in order to sue inheritance class `child` (you might want to capitalize it according to Java code conventions: `Child`) should `extend SuperClass`.

There are many syntax errors, but overall I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
abstract class SuperClass{
    abstract void fill(int a, int b, int c);
    abstract int get();
}

class child extends SuperClass{
    int a, b, c;

    @Override
    void fill(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    int get(){
        return a;
    }

    int get_a(){
        return a;
    }

    int get_b(){
        return b;
    }
    //etc...
}
```